# onChange event inside loop is only passing 0th index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The following code is a input component which uploads an image and I am using a function "handleImageChange" to trigger onChange event. it is inside a loop

```
{images.map((x,i) => (
    <Grid item>
           <Input
              accept="image/*"
              id="change-image-file"
              required
              type="file"
              onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e, i)}
           />
    </Grid>
)}

 const handleImageChange = (e, index) =>{
       conole.log(index)   // whichever index I click it always returns 0
       conole.log(e.target.files[0])  // however e.target.value works alright
 }
```

[image: this is the image in correspondence with the code where I am clicking the 2nd image button but still getting the index 0]

I am using React 18, Material UI 5, and the "Input" & "Grid" is from material UI which resembles HTML "input" & "div" respectively.

Comment: See if replacing MUI Input with html input makes any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Aman** suggests, first move your Grid outside loop. Second thing you should change is that you need to provide **dynamic key and id** to each  element, like this you declare same id to each element and no key at all - React core principle relays on keys when working with loop that outputs component instances.

You should try something like this:

```
<Grid item>
 {images.map((x,i) => (

       <Input
          key={`k-${i}`}
          id={`i-${i}`}
          accept="image/*"
          required
          type="file"
          onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e, i)}
       />
 )}
```

Comment: This was driving me crazy, I had the dynamic key, but not the id. Adding the id made it work. Thanks.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes :)

Answer (score 0):

move your `<Grid>` outside map and than try

```
<Grid item>
     {images.map((x,i) => (

           <Input
              accept="image/*"
              id="change-image-file"
              required
              type="file"
              onChange={(e) => handleImageChange(e, i)}
           />
     )}
</Grid>
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not help

Comment: can you  provide images dummy  json